# Unable to print the content stored in an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, cout

I'm new to C++ programming and I have some trouble displaying the content of an array. The script is very simple and is meant to draw a function f(x); basically after I create the array (x_vect) through a for loop. I want to display what's in it without doing it inside the loop (that would be cheating).

```
// Grafico di una funzione

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h> // serve per poter utilizzare PRINTF e SCANF
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
float x_in, x_fin; // estremi della funzione
float delta_x;     // passo della funzione
int   n;           // numero di passi


// ciclo di controllo sugli estremi dell'intervallo
while (x_fin < x_in) 
{
  cout << endl;
  printf("> Insert extreme values: ");
  scanf("%f" "%f", &x_in, &x_fin); // NB: non va la virgola tra le %f
  cout << endl;
  printf("> number of intervals: ");
  scanf("%d" , &n); // NB: %d se voglio avere un numero intero
    if (x_fin < x_in)
    {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "> Warnign: wrong extreme values (x_fin > x_in)" << endl;
    }
}

delta_x = (x_fin - x_in)/n;
float x_vect[n];
float x = x_in;
x_vect[0]=x;

for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
 x = x + delta_x;
 x_vect[i] = x;
}

cout << x_vect << endl; // HERE'S THE PROBLEM !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

// apertura del file per il salvataggio dei dati
FILE *file; // comando necessario per salvataggio di un file
file = fopen("salvataggio_dati.txt", "wt");
fclose(file); 

cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

But instead of getting the content of x_vect, the script return a weird series of letters and numbers like: 0x7fff4f6e4ec0

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are printing the address of your array (which is what `x_vect`refers to), if you want to print the content of the array you need to loop over it

Comment: Why do you expect getting the content when you are calling by refference?

Comment: you code looks like C code part from the cout lines. there are better/safer options than scanf in C++

Comment: You don't initialize `x_in` and `x_fin` when declared, you then compare them (note: the initial values are undefined). You also use `float x_vect[n];`. This is not currently a part of standard C++ when `n` is not a constant expression (this is supported in C and as a GCC extension).

Comment: As to your "asked" question, you need to iterate over the array to print the individual answers. As it is, you are telling the code to print the address where the array starts. You probably also might consider `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments (they really helped)... i understand what you say guys say... this script is just meant to be a personal tutorial not a professional job... i only thought it was gonna work like in matlab which is a lot more intuitive for me

Answer (score 0):

Since `x_vect` is an array, you need to loop to get its values by doing something like

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
cout << x_vect[i] << endl;
```

Also there are several other problems in your code as mentioned in several comments

Comment: thanks for the replay.... the fact that there are several problems in my code doesn't really bother me since it's the first time i use c++ and my goal is not to become a professional programmer; get over it

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[idone sample](http://ideone.com/vu8h6b)</kbd> showing both of these in action.

**printing the loop:**
`x_vect` is an array and gets passed to `cout` as a pointer `float *`.

The line:

```
cout << x_vect << endl;
```

is printing the pointer address to stdout.

To print a value from the array, you need to dereference the pointer, either with pointer syntax:

```
*(x_vect + x)
```

or with array syntax:

```
x_vect[x]
```

The second is preferable most of the time, but both compile to exactly the same operation.

That prints one value (the one stored at index `x`).  In order to print all of them, we need a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << x_vect[i] << endl;
}
```

Which will then print each value in turn.

**Additional:**

In your `while` loop, you test your values before initialising them. As they could have any value, this will probably not work all the time. E.g. many debuggers cause initialised variables to be initialised as `0` in which case, your loop will *never* fire.

Here is a little modification to solve this:

```
do
{
  cout << "\n> Insert extreme values: ");

  cin >> x_in >> x_fin;

  cout << "\n> number of intervals: ");

  cin >> n;

  
  if (x_fin < x_in)
  {
    cout "\n> Warning: wrong extreme values (x_fin > x_in)" << endl;
  }
} while (x_fin < x_in);
```

the `do {} while();` loop will **always** run through the body of the loop once.  This allows the body to set `x_fin` and `x_in` so that they have valid values when they are first read.

I also standardised using `cin` and `cout` as you shouldn't really mix I/O.  To keep it simple, I didn't do any checks on the input value, you should though.

<kbd>[idone sample](http://ideone.com/vu8h6b)</kbd> showing both of these in action.

Comment: @FedericoGentile is there a reason you un-accepted my answer?